# Show data in controller - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, google-maps, leaflet

this is tricky for me. Problem is, i have api with json file with many items order by ID. I have list with all items, and on click i show detail info for clicked item. In that json file, for all item i have cordinates, lng and latitudes. I use leafet maps. Everything works fine. But now, i want to add maps in info for different item, and show marker only for that clicked item. All cordinates for showing markers are in controller, how to "extract" json file in controller, not in view, to show markers. I hope that you understand me. 
Here is

```js
app.controller("GeoJSONController", ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {


  // Get the items geojson data from a JSON, and here show cordinates

  $http.get("examples/json/JPN.geo.json").success(function(data, status) {
    angular.extend($scope, {
      geojson: {
        data: data,
        style: {
          fillColor: "green",
          weight: 2,
          opacity: 1,
          color: 'white',
          dashArray: '3',
          fillOpacity: 0.7
        }
      }
    });
  });
}]);



//here is example of my json 
{
  "id": 7,
  "created_at": "2016-04-28T12:48:33+0200",
  "updated_at": "2016-04-28T12:48:33+0200",
  "serial_number": "2123124313241235423tisdbjnsdknbasdf",
  "token": "fgjhkfgukfgjkfzhul",
  "type": "urban",
  "description": "opis...",
  "is_active": false,
  "time_zone": null,
  "last_report_dt": null,
  "last_ip": null,
  "active_alarms": [],
  "lat": 37.386339,
  "lng": -122.085823,
  "country": null,
  "city": null
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <div ng-controller="GeoJSONController">
     <leaflet center="japan" geojson="geojson"></leaflet>
</div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Thnxs

Comment: So in your `leaflet` directive, what does `geojson` evaluate to? Can you console.log it out?

Comment: This is only example because i dont have any idea how to fix this...  In my question above,  i take ctrl code from leafet example from  official web page,  but there isn't what i need...  Sry for my english